# Shortest Pong, AI vs AI

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to write the shortest possible Pong game without human interaction, so AI plays vs AI. I assume all of you know Pong, just to make sure, this is the target (just as running code):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeEFMhdnR6c

**The following game rules apply:**

1. No ASCII "graphics".
2. You must actually have code to count the scores, even if the AI never scores.
3. It must be possible to adjust the size of the output window/area in some way to any (reasonable) size. Which means you must include some form of output scaling.
4. No need for a menu or other features of the game, just what's in the video.

**The following [play fair](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) rules apply as well:**

- No language specifically designed for code golfing.
- You may only use standard libraries offered by the language of your choice. No external library downloading, no jQuery, no full-sized game-libraries.
  Exception: if no library for graphical output is available with the default offering of the language of your choice, you are allowed to use a library that offers basic graphical output similar to what other languages include in their basic library set.
- `import` statements (or however they are called in your language) can be skipped in the character count.
- Doorknob-rule: The paddles may not be bigger than 15% of the game area.

**Bonus points:**

- -50 if you include sound. External sound sources (e.g. wav) do not need to be added to the char count and may be downloaded during execution. If you choose to copy & paste the data into the code, only the actual data is allowed to be skipped for character count.
- Another -150 (for -200 total) if you do not use external sounds but generate it. Generate means: you have some form of sound synthesizing, copy & pasting e.g. wav data does not count.

Comment: Your "No language specifically designed for code golfing." rule is basically the *opposite* of "fair"...

Comment: It is very fair, because otherwise the solution would be: `A` Where A is the language specifically designed to display an automatic AI vs AI Pong game.

Comment: Your wording suggests that golfing languages like J or GolfScript disallowed. Perhaps you may want to reword that. In any case, it's automatically disallowed in the first place.

Comment: `No ASCII "graphics".`
That's a bit mean to non-http languages, don't you think?

Comment: I don't think that a drawRect is that much longer than the definition of a colored div with style-sheets, the graphics are not that detailed after all. ;)
And both need to come up with a way to actually move those.

Answer (score 10):

## Pure HTML and CSS, 355 characters

```
<div class=p></div><div style="height:300px"></div><div class=p></div><div id=b></div>0-0<style>.p{width:99px;height:20px;background:#000}*{margin:0}#b{position:absolute;background:#F00;width:20px;height:20px;animation-name:b;animation-duration:3s;animation-iteration-count:infinite;left:40px}@keyframes b{from{top:20px}50%{top:300px}to{top:20px}}</style>
```

You may need an up-to-date or beta browser for the CSS `animation` properties.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvt8E/embedded/result/), with `-webkit-` vendor prefixes added so that it works in latest Chrome.

[image: screenshot]

The ball just bounces back and forth. The AIs are extremely smart and know not to move.

The `0-0` at the bottom is the score, and you can resize the window.

Comment: It is now against the rules, but +1 for pointing that out. :P

Comment: @TwoThe that still will work as long as the ball doesnt go diagonal :P

Comment: @TwoThe Actually, the real playing area is much larger; I just took a small screenshot. See the fiddle.

Comment: It wouldn't be "as the video" anyways. Game field is sideways, ball needs to actually bounce off and paddles need to move.

Comment: @TwoThe You never specified it had to be sideways, the ball does bounce, and the paddles don't move because the AI is smart enough to know that they shouldn't move.

Comment: I specified "this is the target" followed by the video.

Comment: And you are also violating rule #2: There is no code to actually count the scores.

Comment: nitpicking after Doorknob escaped the rules :P

Comment: I just don't feel like writing several pages of rules. If someone doesn't want to play fair, there will always be a loop-hole. ;)

Answer (score 5):

## Scratch, 1605 – 50 = 1555

<s>I don't know how to count the score here and</s> it doesn't meet the "resizing the window" rule... I just thought it was fun. Some unrealistic speed though, and one known bug: if the ball hit the bar at an almost vertical angle, it will somehow get trapped.

Edit: updated score as per [community consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5013/12205).

The bars will only move if the ball is moving towards its direction. I could make it always move, but I think that would be too boring.

Sprite1: the "ball"

[image]

Sprite2: the right vertical "bar" (don't know what it's called)

[image]

Sprite3: the left vertical "bar": essentially the same as Sprite2, except the first `if` condition, which is changed to `direction of Sprite1 < 0`

Note: you can change the "intelligence" of the AI by changing the glide speed. They will move slower, so higher chance of missing the ball.

Sprite4 and Sprite5 are two white vertical bars placed on either side of the "field". They have no scripts.

Code used for byte counting: (Using snippet to hide code)

```html
when green flag clicked
set [score1 v] to [0]
set [score2 v] to [0]
forever 
  go to x: (0) y: (0)
  wait (1) secs
  point in direction (pick random (70) to (290))
  repeat until <<touching [Sprite4 v] ?> or <touching [Sprite5 v] ?>> 
    move (10) steps
    if <touching color [#000] ?> then 
      play sound [pop v]
      point in direction (((360) - (direction)) + (pick random (-5) to (5)))
    end
    if <touching [edge v] ?> then 
      if on edge, bounce
      point in direction ((direction) + (pick random (-5) to (5)))
    end
  end
  play sound [216090__richerlandtv__bad-beep-incorrect v]
  if <touching [Sprite4 v] ?> then 
    change [score1 v] by (1)
  end
  if <touching [Sprite5 v] ?> then 
    change [score2 v] by (1)
  end
end

when green flag clicked
forever 
  if <[0] < ([direction v] of [Sprite1 v])> then 
    if <([y position v] of [Sprite1 v]) > [140]> then 
      glide (.1) secs to x: (x position) y: (140)
    else 
      if <([y position v] of [Sprite1 v]) < [-140]> then 
        glide (.1) secs to x: (x position) y: (-140)
      else 
        glide (.1) secs to x: (x position) y: ([y position v] of [Sprite1 v])
      end
    end
  end
end

when green flag clicked
forever 
  if <([direction v] of [Sprite1 v]) < [0]> then 
    if <([y position v] of [Sprite1 v]) > [140]> then 
      glide (.1) secs to x: (x position) y: (140)
    else 
      if <([y position v] of [Sprite1 v]) < [-140]> then 
        glide (.1) secs to x: (x position) y: (-140)
      else 
        glide (.1) secs to x: (x position) y: ([y position v] of [Sprite1 v])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

<sub>Note: Code automatically generated using [scratchblocks generator](http://scratchblocks.github.io/generator/), modified as somehow the generator doesn't correctly handle decimal numbers (treating .1 as 0).</sub>

See it run online [here](http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/19002979/).

[Old version](http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/19000484/) (the bars move randomly).

A screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I like that XD Whether or not that qualifies as "No use of full solution libraries" I leave up to the community votes. If you manage to join the Y-position of the paddles with the one of the ball, the AD should turn into AI, however there is no requirement for them being smart. ;)

Comment: @TwoThe Thanks for the tip, see edit.

Comment: Could someone please add the byte count? http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5013/34718

Comment: @mbomb007 Done.

Answer (score 2):

## HTML / JavaScript, 476

```html
<body onload="for(p in r=c.getClientRects()[0])top[p[0]]=c[p]=r[p];t=c.getContext('2d');t.T=t.fillText;t.R=t.fillRect;A=B=0;a=b=h/2;H=h/9|0;x=w/2;y=h/2;v=w/550;z=h/250;setInterval('x<w/3&&(a+=a<y?3:-3);x>2*w/3&&(b+=b<y?3:-3);y<0|y>h?z=-z:0;x<8&&y>a&&y<a+H||x>w-8&&y>b&&y<b+H?v=-v:0;x+=v;y+=z;(x<0?++A:x>w?++B:0)&&(x=w/2,y=h/2);with(t)clearRect(0,0,w,h),R(x,y,5,5),R(2,a,6,H),R(w-8,b,6,H),T(A,H,9),T(B,w-H,9)',16)"><style>*{margin:0;width:100%;height:100%}</style><canvas id=c>
```

**Un-golfed:**

```html
<body>
<style>*{margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;}</style>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script>
// Resize canvas
for(p in r=c.getClientRects()[0])top[p[0]]=c[p]=r[p];

// Get drawing context
t = c.getContext('2d');

// Shorter names
t.T=t.fillText;t.R=t.fillRect;

// Scores
A=B=0;

// Paddles position
a=b=h/2;
H=h/9|0;

// Ball position
x=w/2;
y=h/2;

// Ball velocity
dx=w/550;
dy=h/250;

setInterval(function() {
  // Process AI
  x<w/3&&(a+=a<y?3:-3);
  x>2*w/3&&(b+=b<y?3:-3);

  // Wall collisions
  y<0|y>h?dy=-dy:0;

  // Paddle collisions
  x<8&&y>a&&y<a+H||x>w-8&&y>b&&y<b+H?dx=-dx:0;

  // Update ball position
  x+=dx;
  y+=dy;

  // Update score if the ball is behind the paddle.
  // If so, reset the ball position
  (x<0?++A:x>w?++B:0)&&(x=w/2,y=h/2);

  with(t){
    // Clear screen
    clearRect(0,0,w,h);

    // Draw ball
    R(x,y,5,5);

    // Draw paddles
    R(2,a,6,H);
    R(w-8,b,6,H);

    // Draw scores
    T(A,H,9);
    T(B,w-H,9);
  }
},16);
</script>
</body>
```